# C++ MFC MDI data as Document not on disk

Tags: c++, mfc, mdi

I would like to use MFC MDI but my data (Document) is not on the disk.

I have functions that generate data according to the input. 
Data of type A, type B etc.

I would like to open a new tab for every new data generated.

For example, if the input of the generated data is X, I would like to open a new tab with the name X on it. If the X exists, I would like to activate (bring front) the X tab as the MDI already does.

My idea is to have multiple CMultiDocTemplate. Each one generated by different CDocument/CView derived class.

I am looking for a solution to overload the open/new function so instead of opening a file from disk, ask from my functions to generate the data (CDocument).

Also, I don't want the user to choose between CMultiDocTemplate/Cview but I want to choose which one to use for the new tab.

Comment: I will say I did something like this a long time ago (using vc++ 6.0), but I am not sure it is possible any longer, it required building a custom build of the MFC library. The requirement that a serialized document be backed by a disk file has long been a major peeve of mine when it comes to using MFC.

Comment: The solution I found is to CreateNewDocument with CMultiDocTemplate and then CreateNewFrame for this document.

Comment: I had developed an MFC app with multiple document and view types, a long time ago. Basically you need one doc-template for each doctype/viewtype combination. And you need to keep the doc-template instances you create during initialization, if you want to create a view window of a certain type. As for creating documents from data acquired from a source other than a disk-file, you need to dig deep into the MFC code, check what can be changed (eg what is virtual), and if not, write your own functions. Check what CWinApp::OnFileNew and OnFileOpen do. Override or take code snippets from there.

Comment: You can also switch the view for the document to another based on the document type.

Comment: @ConstantineGeorgiou Thanks a lot for the reply. I will follow your suggestion. 
I think about this solution before but I was looking if there is a simpler way to do this.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle thanks for the reply. The main problem is to find a way to use MDI and the functionality without having my data on the disk. what you suggest is a step I will probably need in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is what you might be looking for, but I used code like this to change the view to a different one based on the document being loaded:

```
BOOL CCommunityTalksDoc::SwitchToView(CRuntimeClass* pNewViewClass)
{
    POSITION        rPos;
    CView           *pOldActiveView;
    CFrameWnd       *pChild;
    CCreateContext  context;
    BOOL            bAutoDelete;

    rPos = GetFirstViewPosition();
    pOldActiveView = GetNextView(rPos);
    pChild = pOldActiveView->GetParentFrame();

    // If we're already displaying this kind of view, no need to go further.
    if (pOldActiveView->IsKindOf(pNewViewClass))
        return TRUE;

    // Set flag so that document will not be deleted when view is destroyed.
    bAutoDelete = m_bAutoDelete;
    m_bAutoDelete = FALSE;
    // Delete existing view
    pOldActiveView->DestroyWindow();
    // restore flag
    m_bAutoDelete = bAutoDelete;

    // Create new view.
    m_pScriptView = (CScriptParseView*)pNewViewClass->CreateObject();
    if (m_pScriptView == nullptr)
    {
        TRACE1("Warning: Dynamic create of view type %s failed\n", pNewViewClass->m_lpszClassName);
        return FALSE;
    }

    // we must ensure the popup dialogues don't display
    m_pScriptView->SetBuildMode(FALSE);

    // Draw new view.
    context.m_pNewViewClass = pNewViewClass;
    context.m_pCurrentDoc = this;
    context.m_pNewDocTemplate = nullptr;
    context.m_pLastView = nullptr;
    context.m_pCurrentFrame = pChild;
    if (!m_pScriptView->Create(nullptr, nullptr, AFX_WS_DEFAULT_VIEW, CRect(0, 0, 0, 0), 
                pChild, AFX_IDW_PANE_FIRST, &context))
    {
        TRACE0("Warning: couldn't create view for frame\n");
        delete m_pScriptView;
        m_pScriptView = nullptr;
        return FALSE; 
    }

    m_pScriptView->SendMessage(WM_INITIALUPDATE, 0, 0);  // WM_INITIALUPDATE is defined in afxpriv.h
    pChild->RecalcLayout();
    m_pScriptView->UpdateWindow();
    pChild->SetActiveView(m_pScriptView);
    return TRUE;
}
```

You use it like:

```
CRuntimeClass *pNewViewClass = RUNTIME_CLASS(CScriptParseView);
if (!SwitchToView(pNewViewClass))
{
    // fail, don't know why it would fail
    ASSERT(FALSE);
}
```